# RestKit mapping: map different objects at once

Tags: ios, rest, networking, restkit

I've got a JSON like this

```
{
  "result" : 1,
  "messages" : [],
  "users" : {}
}
```

Both `messages` and `users` are populated.

If I want to map, say, `messages`, I do the following:

```
messageMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[OLMessage class]];
[messageMapping mapKeyPath:@"user_id" toAttribute:@"userID"];
[messageMapping mapKeyPath:@"status" toAttribute:@"status"];
[messageMapping mapKeyPath:@"text" toAttribute:@"text"];
[messageMapping mapKeyPath:@"date_time" toAttribute:@"date_time"];

messageManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:baseURL];
[messageManager.mappingProvider setMapping:messageMapping forKeyPath:@"messages"];

[messageManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/messages/fetch" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) { ... };
```

and I got my messages.

How do I set up my mappings to get `users` with the same call to `loadObjectsAtResourcePath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping in a similar way and set:

```
[messageManager.mappingProvider setMapping: userMapping forKeyPath:@"users"];
```

Comment: I've already solved my question with plain JSON parsing, so your answer will be used in future. However, could you please tell me, how I will get my data? Will there be a two calls to `onDidLoadObjects` or something?

Comment: onDidLoadObjects will be called once with an array of all the objects that were created (both types)